# Bootstrap: center any span

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, alignment

I have a problem when using a class to center my `span` :

```
.center {
    float:none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="center span5">
    <button></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

This does not work, apparently it is overridden by bootstrap row-* CSS. However if I include the same style in the div directly (`style="..."`) it works.

I think it doesn't work because it doesn't knows the width, so I tried to use an offset, but then when the button isn't centered as well as with the .CSS. I can't specify a width since my `button` width is set by external JavaScript.

How can I make the .center class work in that case?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As of Bootstrap 2.3.0 you can use the built in class `.text-center`.

```
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span12 text-center">

    My content to be centered here

    </div>

</div>
```

It worked perfectly for me... :)

Comment: Thanks! This is definitely the cleanest approach.

Answer (score 9):

You can center it with:

```
.center {
   margin: 0 auto !important;
   float: none !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WesWz/2/)

Or you can use:

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"].center, .center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;
}
```

I tend to avoid `!important` because you never know when it may differ with some other CSS. Interestingly, the above affect differs on both .row and .row-fluid.

Comment: Please don't use `!important`. It's a sledgehammer. If you use it and then want to override it, then you can't make something double!important, so you have the same problem all over again … just with !important everywhere.

Comment: Agreed. I didn't notice it was `row-fluid` at first, and tried `row` in my initial tweak (see the [unnumbered JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WesWz/)). That was my first tweak to make it work, then I got it working without it.

Comment: Works well with the second solution, nice!

Answer (score 3):

When using the auto-margin method, you must define a width to the element. It can be any unit, but it must be defined:

```
.center {
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

:)

Comment: I added the width but somehow the span5 is still not centered, its size is correct and when I inspect the element I see it but it's indeed not centered :/.

Answer (score 2):

```
.class {
    margin:auto; 
    display:table;
}
```

Idk why, but it always works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it doesn't work because it doesn't knows the width

This can't be true because:

> if I include the same style in the div directly (style="...") it works

… and if it didn't know the width in one case, then it wouldn't in the other either.

If using a `style` attribute works, then that is a sign that the problem is one of specificity. Write the selector of your ruleset so that the [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) is greater then that of whatever rule is overriding those properties (or so that the specificity is equal but the ruleset appears later in the stylesheet).

You can use the Developer Tools of your browser to see which rules are being applied to the element so you can see the selector you have to be more specific than.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the explanation! I accepted pickypg's answer since he provided the code sample for the fix.

Answer (score 1):

For **Bootstrap 4**. Say for parent `div` you can put in this:

```
class='... justify-content-center text-center m-auto'
```

`justify-content` is for common case

Comment: The `m-auto` was not necessary for me